# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push') while QRcode reading library

Tags: android, npm, react-native, qr-code

I try to read QRcode with react native
then I install library

and this is my code

```
  'use strict';

    var React = require('react-native');
    var {
      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      TouchableOpacity,
      NavigatorIOS,
    } = React;

    var QRCodeScreen = require('./QRCodeScreen');   

  var cameraApp = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (
          <NavigatorIOS
            style={styles.container,{ width:100,height:500}}
            initialRoute={{
              title: 'Index',
              backButtonTitle: 'Back',
              component: Index,
            }}
          />        
        );
      }
    });    

    var Index = React.createClass({        
      render: function() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressQRCode} >
              <Text>Read QRCode</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        );
      },        
      _onPressQRCode: function() {
        this.props.navigator.push({
          component: QRCodeScreen,
          title: 'QRCode',
          passProps: {
            onSucess: this._onSucess,
          },
        });
      },        
      _onSucess: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      },

    });           


    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',        
      },
      contentContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }
    });

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyFirstReactapril', () => cameraApp);
```

but I get this Error 
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')

and I don't know what is wrong with it , please help.
Or is there any library can read QRCode and gives me the link or string?

Comment: hey, you register the Index Component ,not the cameraApp,btw put the Child Component in the top is better

Comment: @liupluto Nothing changed , still have the Error

Answer (score 0):

[NavigatorIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html) component works only in iOS. You need to use [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) component which will work in both Android and iOS.

Comment: thanks for you precious time, but I already replace it, but the problem is, it didn't appear any thing on Android  emulator

Comment: But how can Navigator read my QRcode ?, Sorry for being little dummy I am new with mobile apps all :)

Comment: Navigator component is used to transition between different scenes of the app. You need to use a QRCode scanning library to read QRCode. You may refer https://github.com/jicksonp/ReactEvalApp project. This has qrcode scanning functionality.

Comment: Ok @Jickson I copy what inside QRcodeRow.js file in my index page and also Copy the files related to this page '../utils/Globals';
'../utils/Utils';
Then it gives me an error `undefined is an object ('evaluating 'this.props.qrcode.code')`

Comment: Hey.. https://egghead.io/lessons/react-react-native-up-and-running this is a good tutorial to learn the basics of react-native. This will help you understand the basics of react native. You will be able understand the sample projects and implement after following this tutorial. All the best.