# apk didn't run on mobile android react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have my project with react native 
then I tried to make apk
So I use this command `gradlew assembleRelease`

and it create an file named with `app-release-unsigned.apk` 
in this Directory 
`C:\Users\nesreen\Desktop\MyFirstReactapril\android\app\build\outputs\apk`
Then I copy this file to my android mobile and try to run it but always gives me `App not installed`

please help , I wonder what is missing or wrong on my process.

Comment: Unsigned apk won't install on mobile. please try to sign your android apk
Check this https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: Generate signed apk using the following https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html in react native.

Comment: @dindinii Thanks I will give it a try

Comment: @Jickson thanks I will give it a try , but please can you have a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690162/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-navigator-push-while-qrcode ?