# react-native compiled apk wont run on device

Tags: android, react-native

Walkthrought with react-native tutorial (**react-native 0.30**):
I created app which couldn't be installed on android device here are steps:

1. react-native init demo
2. cd android
3. gradlew assembleRelease
4. Copying unsigned apk to mobile device ( htc m8 mini 2 )

and got result : `Application demo was not installed`

Based on this similiar question [apk didn't run on mobile android react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706499/apk-didnt-run-on-mobile-android-react-native):
Unsigned apk won't install on mobile.

But why I am able to run unsiged application made by Ionic 2?

Whats the problem?

Comment: have you build Node.js bridge connection before app install from android studio ?

Comment: no. I dont know what is it. However I am able to test app in Genymotion emulator after react-native run android & react-native start

Comment: is there any error in command prompt or android studio logcat ?

Comment: no, there were not any errors.

Comment: You have to add device for first time apk install form android studio

Comment: no. I just followed facebook's react-native tutorial

Answer (score 7):

In Ionic 2 you run a debug apk, its not possible to run an unsigned apk.

What you can do in react is sign your apk and run.

The first setup can be a little complex, but after you complete the setup is very easy to generate a signed apk when you need it.

You can follow these instructions to sign your apk:

**Generating a signing key**

You can generate a private signing key using keytool.

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

This command prompts you for passwords for the keystore and key, and to provide the Distinguished Name fields for your key. It then generates the keystore as a file called my-release-key.keystore.

The keystore contains a single key, valid for 10000 days. The alias is a name that you will use later when signing your app, so remember to take note of the alias.

*Note: Remember to keep your keystore file private and never commit it to version control.*

**Setting up gradle variables**

1. Place the `my-release-key.keystore` file under the `android/app`
   directory in your project folder.
2. Edit the file `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and add the following
   (replace ***** with the correct keystore password, alias and key
   password),

> MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
>
> MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
>
> MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
>
> MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****

These are going to be global gradle variables, which we can later use in our gradle config to sign our app.

> **Note about saving the keystore:** Once you publish the app on the Play
>   Store, you will need to republish your app under a different package
>   name (losing all downloads and ratings) if you want to change the
>   signing key at any point. So backup your keystore and don't forget the
>   passwords. Note about security: If you are not keen on storing your
>   passwords in plaintext and you are running OSX, you can also store
>   your credentials in the Keychain Access app. Then you can skip the two
>   last rows in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties.`

Adding signing config to your app's gradle config 
Edit the file `android/app/build.gradle` in your project folder and add the signing config,

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
...
```

**Generating the release APK**

Simply run the following in a terminal:

```
$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Gradle's assembleRelease will bundle all the JavaScript needed to run your app into the APK. If you need to change the way the JavaScript bundle and/or drawable resources are bundled (e.g. if you changed the default file/folder names or the general structure of the project), have a look at android/app/build.gradle to see how you can update it to reflect these changes.

The generated APK can be found under `android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk`, and is ready to be distributed.

**Testing the release build of your app**

Before uploading the release build to the Play Store, make sure you test it thoroughly. Install it on the device using:

```
$ cd android && ./gradlew installRelease
```

Note that installRelease is only available if you've set up signing as described above.

You can kill any running packager instances, all your and framework JavaScript code is bundled in the APK's assets.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I would check it out and test if it works. Since unsigned apk buit wish gradlew assembleRelease (apk-unaligned...) wont be installed. After copying apk to device: I got  App was not installed. Now let me check with signing it.

Comment: app is installing but crashing after launch ,

Answer (score 0):

@EvghenyKalkutin if you are beginner in react-native then just follow this simple step

1. Download chocolatey from your cmd just write this code in cmd `@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin`
2. after successfully install the chocolatey now install node.js and Python2 using chocolatey. for this use this code for install node.js `choco install nodejs.install` and install Python@ use this code `choco install python2`
3. ok now open node.js command promt and run this code `npm install -g react-native-cli` to start react-native
4. ok now download sample project using this code `react-native init AwesomeProject` or `react-native init HelloWorld`  :)
5. Now go to the directory where this project downloaded using `cd AwesomeProject`
6. Start android stduio and open this project and correct your gradle error if it occurs(and clean project) and connect your device with usb debugging
7. and check your device is available or not using this code `adb devices`
8. if device is available then convert it's port for the react native using this code `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
9. now perform this code `npm start` for the build node.js bridge
10. after build the node.js bridge now start your project using this code `react-native run-android` and here you go your sample project is run on your device

**And for unsign apk or assembleRelease just go through below step **

11. just write this code in node.js command prompt `cd android && gradlew clean && gradlew assembleRelease`

    **I use windows os so all this instructions are for windows os I don't know this code is same for mac os or linux os**
    i hope this wiil help you for start up in react-native. if any problem just comment it.

Answer (score 0):

**WINDOWS USERS**
FOLLOW THESE INSTRUCTIONS ....IT WORKED FOR ME

**Prerequisite** - You must have a `keystore file`, If you don't have then Open `cmd` run `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` follow instructions and you are done.You will have a keystore file. Now follow these steps.

1 .On windows `cd android` and then run `gradlew assembleRelease` in **Editor Terminal** or **Command Prompt** in **your project directory**.

2 .Find APK at this location

```
android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk
```

3 .Copy this `APK` to bin folder of jdk installation directory ( for me directory was `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin` ) [ Basically in this step we are trying to go to the same directory as `jarsigner`]

4 .Also Copy your `keystore` file to this ( `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin` ) directory.

5 .Now Open `cmd` in **Administrator** mode and run

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin
```

6 .Now run

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <<your keystore file name >>  <<your apk file name>> alias_name
```

Here goes your apk , now find your signed apk here cd `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin` . Install it, Now it should install.